# Need to run "setup:static-content:deploy -f" every time to update css in magento 2 developer mode

Tags: caching, magento2

:: Magneto 2.3
:: mode : developer

[CMD SCREEN SHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tADId.png)

In CMD after run command getting the warning: Manual static content deployment is not required in "default" and "developer" modes.

But not getting the latest CSS changes in - pub\static\frontend

If I changed in **CSS** then not get the result in Front-end.
If I run **setup:static-content:deploy ** then also not update css in pub\static\frontend

If I **setup:static-content:deploy -f** (-f Forced) then CSS will update in
pub\static\frontend

WHY CSS does not update in "setup:static-content:deploy" command 
or any way : without "setup:static-content:deploy" command css update automatically in (pub\static\frontend)

Answer (score 0):

May be Your cache is enable 
to check cache status try   `php bin/magento c:st`
to disable cache try `php bin/magento c:d`

Also shortcut for `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f` 
is `php bin/magento s:st:d -f`

In Some cases , you browser cache the CSS in this case you need to disable cache for browser.

For Chrome :

Select the “Menu” button in the upper-right corner, then select `“More tools” > “Developer tools“`. You can also get to this screen by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + I` for Windows and Linux or `Command + Option + I` for Mac OS X.
The Dev Tools window appears. Select `“Network“`,
Check the `“Disable cache”` box.

Comment: You mean cache should be disabled if I want CSS update automatically without "setup:static-content:deploy -f" every time.
Right now I need run "setup:static-content:deploy -f" every time for CSS update.

Comment: Yes you can try it.